# LINQ Query fails while adding additional condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ expression.

```
Category category = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryURL == categoryurl);
```

Categories list has Classnames list and I would like to add another confition to check for Active = 'Y'.  I tried the following, but doesn't work.  Any ideas??

```
Category category = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryURL == categoryurl && x.ClassNames.Active == "Y");
```

I get the following error.

> 'ICollection<ClassName>' does not contain a definition for 'Active'
> and no accessible extension method 'Active' accepting a first argument
> of type 'ICollection'

Comment: Should all class names fulfill the condition? Or ist it ok if any class name fulfills the condition?

Comment: `x.ClassNames` is a collection of `ClassName` objects, so do you need to check if *any* of them are `Active == "Y"` or *all* of them?

Comment: Yes, I need to check if any of them are active and return active list as Category

Comment: `&& x.ClassNames.Any(y => y.Active == "Y")`

Comment: Yes, all Classnames should full fill the condition and return list of Category

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I changed it to  Category category = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryURL == categoryurl && x.ClassNames.Any(y => y.Active == "Y"));, but it returns NULL.

Comment: @WinFXGuy That may be correct, you haven't shown your data in the question.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay  I should be returning a collection of five Category objects.  Without that condition, I return 6 and one of them is with Active = "N"

Comment: @WinFXGuy Then you should be using `Where` rather than `SingleOrDefault`, although if there are 5 categories that have a classname with `Active == "Y"`, then `SingleOrDefault` should throw an exception.

Comment: You keep changing the question, don't do that.

Comment: Always show a class model when asking LINQ questions and also mention the ORM you're using (including its version).

Answer (score 0):

`x.ClassNames` is a collection of `ClassName` objects, so if you need to check if *any* of them are `Active == "Y"`, you can use Linq [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0):

```
Category category = db.Categories
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryURL == categoryurl && 
                          x.ClassNames.Any(c => c.Active == "Y"));
```

Comment: Please see my comment to @JohnathanBarclay

Answer (score -2):

You can't use the property "ClassNames" from the list like the
Use Any or All to check all items in the list.

```
Category category = db.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryURL == categoryurl && x.ClassNames.All(className => className.Active== "Y"));
```

Comment: `Include` is to eagerly load navigation properties, not to facilitate the `WHERE` clause. Also `x.ClassNames.Active` will not compile, because `ClassNames` is of type `ICollection<ClassName>`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Sorry I missed that, I updated the Answer.

Comment: You still don't need to use `Include` - it's not helping.

Comment: And also it needs a capital `I`

Comment: Remove include at all, it is just for eager loading.